# Using segue from a subview

Tags: iphone, ios6, segue, uicollectionview, uistoryboardsegue

I have view which contains a collection view.  I have added this collection view programatically (in viewDidLoad) - so that is not on the storyboard.  This collection view contains several cells.  When a user clicks on one of the cells in the collection view, I want to segue to a different view controller (that I plan to add on the storyboard).  My question is - since the collection view is not on storyboard, how can I segue out of that? Or is there other way to accomplish that.

Some updates to the original question above:

In Parent View Controller, I do the following:

```
//Layout for the collection view
CDLayout *cdLayout = [[CDLayout alloc] initWithItemSize:CGSizeMake(cardWidth, cardHeight) withItemInsets:UIEdgeInsetsMake(topInset, leftInset, bottomInset, rightInset) withInterItemSpacingX:8.0f withTopMargin:margin withLeftMargin:margin withBottomMargin:margin withRightMargin:margin shouldRotate:NO];

//This is the collection view controller
CDLineLayoutViewController *cdLineVC = [[CDLineLayoutViewController alloc] initWithCollectionViewLayout:cdLayout withItemCount:12 ];

// add the collection view controller to self - the parent    
[self addChildViewController:cdLineVC];

[cdLineVC didMoveToParentViewController:self];

// add collectionView as a subview
[self.view addSubview:cdLineVC.collectionView];
```

The collectionView has 12 cards.  When a user clicks on one of the cards I want to move to another view controller.

As you can see the collection view is not on the storyboard.  So, is there a way to create a segue?

BTW, one option is what Taseen suggested below.  I tried that and it is working.  But as I understand it is not actually a "segue."

Answer (score 2):

Can you please show us any code you have written

What i have understood from your question is that you have added collection view in **viewDidLoad.** and i believe you have set the delegate of collection view to self, So in 
**didSelectItemAtIndexPath** method you can write this code

```
 -(void)collectionView:(UICollectionView *)collectionView didSelectItemAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    //From indexpath.item, you know which cell was clicked

    //using switch method

    switch (indexPath.item) {
        case 0:
            //You Can push the view controller from here
            //You need to import the header file of that View controller
           DestinationViewController *destinationView;

            //if the self controller in which the collection view is shown is embedded in Navigation controller,
            //you can push using
            [self.navigationController pushViewController:destinationView animated:YES];

            //if it is not embedded, use modal segue
            [self.modalViewController presentModalViewController:destinationView animated:YES];


            break;

        default:
            break;
    }
}
```

**EDIT:** The segue you will create on the storyboard from your **ParentViewController** to **DestinationController** will have segueIdentifier property. like shown below
[image]
then in **didSelectItemAtIndexPath** instead of pushing the controller you can use this code

```
[self performSegueWithIdentifier:@"collectionViewSegue" sender:self];
```

you can also configure the destination view controller using prepareForSegue method..

```
   -(void)prepareForSegue:(UIStoryboardSegue *)segue sender:(id)sender
{
    DestinationViewController *targetVC = (DestinationViewCOntroller *)segue.destinationViewController;
    //if you pass anything you can do it here
    //if to set any public variable for example image for the imageview
    targetVC.cardImageView.image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"queen.png"];
}
```

This method will be in your parent controller.

Answer (score 0):

Create a new segue by ctrl-click on the initial viewController and drag to the destination viewController. Don't forget to set the segue identifier. 
than overwrite the -(void)performSegueWithIdentifier:(NSString *)identifier sender:(id)sender method.

Comment: How will I identify which item in the collection view got selected (or tapped)?  Shouldn't there be a way to handle segue in the subview (in this case collection view) controller.

Comment: The sender object which is the second argument of the performSegueWith... method is tapped object. Every view object has the NSInteger property _tag_. assign ever view object with an unique number. With this number you can identify the view objects which was tapped.

Comment: May be the easy way is don't use segues. @Taseen solution is the better way.